# opposite of collation (the act of removing leading zeros)

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the act of removing leading zeros from a number? I need to abbreviate it at one point so it needs to be a single word, or multiple words that are fairly distinct from others when abbreviated together.

Comment: Good question.  I would have suggested *decollation* if that didn't mean the act of beheading someone.  By the way, I would have given this question a +1, but I've already used all my votes for the day. :-(

Comment: Careful with significance.

Comment: @user116032 it's a batch program, so there aren't even decimal numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word [*trim*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098688/how-to-remove-all-leading-zeroes-in-a-string) is sometimes used for this purpose in a programming context.

Comment: I think trim might indeed be the best to use in my case, and you reminded me that it's a good idea to have it trim leading and trailing spaces aswell.

Answer (score 0):

"To collate" is a quite generic term. An opposite, generic as well, but understandable in the context, is "[to trim](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9c642ca6-19f1-408c-a457-4f63221467be/trim-leading-zeros)".